# NullPointerException on NetworkInfo

Tags: android

I am programming a service that runs when you boot the phone, but you need an Internet connection and connection to send SMS operator.
I wrote a function to `ConnectionManager` as in other post appears, but I always get the same answer: `NullPointerException`, when I do the following:

I define `cm` as `ConnectionManager` and

```
NetworkInfo NetInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo();
```

Is it not because of this?

How can I fix it?

Sorry if I did not put all the code ...

I have the following in the OnStart () method of a service that is activated by ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED ...

```
@ Override
public void OnStart (Intent intent, int start) {

    Context aplCtx = getApplicationContext ();


    IsConnected boolean = false;
    while (! IsConnected) {
        try {
            IsConnected = IsOnline (aplCtx);

        } Catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d (e.toString ());
        }
    }

    .....  
}

private boolean IsOnline (Context ctx) {

    boolean result = false;

    try {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService     (Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        cm.getActiveNetworkInfo NetworkInfo ni = ();

        if (ni! = null) {
           if (ni.getState () == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
               result = true;
           }
        }
        return result;
}
```

Since this is a background function and after starting the Smartphone, the operating system to force kill the process, before we get an Internet connection. How I can resolve this?,
How do I get the operating system does not kill the process and have an Internet connection to perform the following actions?

Answer (score 1):

Without your code, We can't say anything what going wrong,

But to get network info I am using this, If you are not make a mistake then it also works,

```
public static boolean netConnect(Context ctx){
    ConnectivityManager cm ; 
    NetworkInfo info = null;

    try {
        cm = (ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();        

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("connectivity", e.toString());
    }

    if(info != null){
          return info.isConnected();
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a problem here. info will be set to a NetworkInfo object, but you haven't actually tested to see if it is connected to a network, or connecting. Merely that the object is not null is not enough to say for sure.

info.isAvailable() and/or info.isConnected() should be used before you return out of the method.

Comment: @Andrew Weir - Thanks for your comment. I updated my answer. Now its correct.

Comment: I used this code, but i have internet and i'm getting false. :/